# Line 5: 'tags' is missing in props validation react/prop-types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

ESlint is giving me this warning when I am compiling my code. We are using the AirBNB config.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProfileInterestSkillButtons = ({
    tags, title, user, member,
}) => {

    return (
        <div>
           {title}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProfileInterestSkillButtons;
```

Comment: At least paste the code including the 'line 5' here?

Comment: thanks! just added a stripped down version of the react component

Comment: So, you're not doing any validation and you wondering why you're getting a warning saying you're not doing validation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your component is using a prop named `tags` that it is receiving from its parent component.

ESLint is just warning you to define a type check for that prop in the component where you are using it. You can do that by either using `PropTypes` or by using `flow`.

Simple example using PropType would be:

```
... // other imports
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

... // your component declaration

ProfileInterestSkillButtons.propTypes = {
  tags: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  ... // and more
};

export default ProfileInterestSkillButtons;
```

PropType: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Flow: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/

Answer (score 0):

### Using Flow

Quick recipe to type-check props using flow.

```js
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StatusBar, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ScreenDefaultView = (props: { layout: Node, scrollableLayout?: boolean } ) => {
    const layout = props.layout;
    const scrollableLayout = props.scrollableLayout;
    return ( ...
```

**Note:** in order to add ***Optional Parameters*** or also called in Flow ***maybe type*** just add a `?`.

```js
// scrollableLayout? is optional note the ? 
props: { layout: Node, scrollableLayout?: boolean }
```

### Flow Documentation

- [Predicate Functions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions)